# Display a 3D mesh as a kivy widget?

Tags: python, 3d, kivy

Is there a way to display a generated 3D mesh (`.ply` file) as a kivy widget inside a window (and possibly control it)?

Comment: If you download the kivy source code, there is a `3Drendering` example that would be a good place to start.

Comment: I think that comes with a custom GLSL renderer. There probably should be a way to use Open3D or PyMesh inside a widget, right?

Comment: The core things to do are draw a Kivy Mesh, write some shaders that do what you want when it comes to rendering it in 3D, and set up the widget to use those. That's basically what the 3d rendering example does, it is a good reference for what you need to do.